Implementation of the cascade classifier in the mlr3
I have a predictor variable with five classes and each algorithm classifies one of the classes of this variable well. Can I make a classifier with all these algorithms and have each one classify its corresponding class?
I have looked in the manual and googled but have not found the solution. The following code is not valid because the key 'cascade' does not exist:
# Create the cascade classifier
cascade <- po('cascade',
po('select', id = 'class3', selector = function(x) x[, 3]),
rst.e[[['kknn']]],
po('select', id = 'class4', selector = function(x) x[, 4])
rst.e[['xgboost1']],
po('select', id = 'class2', selector = function(x) x[, 2])
rst.e[['ctree']],
po('select', id = 'class5', selector = function(x) x[, 5])
rst.e[['xgboost2']],
po('select', id = 'class1', selector = function(x) x[, 1])
rst.e[[['multinom']]]])

Any help would be appreciated.
